# Consuming a WCF service using jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have been looking at this problem for the last couple of days and getting nowhere. I have tried all manner of tutorials and for various reasons I can't get anything to work. All I want to do is call a WCF service from a simple HTML page using jQuery. All I get at the moment is "bad request".

I have everything hosted in the same virtual directory within IIS so it's definitely not a cross-domain issue.

Here is my web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="WcfJqueryTest">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfJqueryTest.IService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
 </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is my service code and interface

```
namespace WcfJqueryTest
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetData();
}

namespace WcfJqueryTest
{
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "Hello world";
    }
}
}
```

And finally my jQuery

```
function myFunction () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/wcfjquerytest/service.svc/getdata",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        alert(status);
        alert(error);
    }
})
};
```

I have tried many a tutorial and searched everywhere but I'm still none the wiser. Any pointers are very much appreciated.

Cheers,

Neil.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service

Comment: I have seen his tutorial before and tried using it but to no avail.

Comment: Try enabling tracing at the service, it should tell why it's considering the request to be bad.

Comment: How does the data you send look like? Are you sure its sent as json? As contentType only says what the data should be, not what you actually send. Edit: nevermind, you dont send anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, right click your svc file and click "View Markup"

```
<%@ ServiceHost 
    Language="C#" 
    Debug="true" 
    Service="MyService.Service" 
    CodeBehind="Service.svc.cs" 
    Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" //Add this line
%>
```

This will auto-config your service(it overides the settings you made in web.config).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that and now I get **Internal Server Error**. Time for some tracing I think.

Comment: Looks like my IIS had a few issues, a machine reboot and it's now working, cheers :-)